# Logging into SiteMinder using Java

Tags: java, httpclient, siteminder

As I am working on the project that is making a call to a url and that url is using siteminder so every time I make a request to that url

```
https://some-host/a/getmeta?id=10
```

it redirects me to some other url that contains siteminder thing

```
location: https://login.somehost.com/siteminderagent/nocert/1309460767/smgetcre
d.scc?TYPE=16777217&REALM=-SM-Documentum%20[12%3a06%3a07%3a4932]&SMAUTHREASON=0&
METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-6D9yKpar83ASDc5Sb4KDjZtHgfZId%2fYHFKbzwYvx5EUeGMi0dOa
uGVx6wOk1daI3&TARGET=-SM-http%3A%2F%2Fsome-host%2Fa%2Fgetmeta%3Fid%3D10
```

And If I open this link into the browser then it ask for the username and password and If I provide the username and password then I get my actual content back..

So how can I authenticate everytime and I am using HTTPCLIENT 4.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can follow the redirect, fill in the fields and post the form. It will take you where you want to go.

The fields are probably the standard USER and PASSWORD fields from siteminder. you just need to ensure your java code properly handles the redirects and maintains the cookie.  The commons-httpclient does this for you pretty easily.

Comment: And how can I capture this username and password values, that a person is trying to enter in a popup..

Comment: Is your httpclient code running inside a web server? Can you not simply present them with a form for credentials? once they submit the form you will have the username and password to use when communicating with the backend server.

Comment: I have no control over that form.. As that popup window is controlled by SiteMinder.. So i cannot do anything.. I think there is some way in the SM_SESSION through that I can login with each user.. Any idea..

Comment: If you're making a call to https://some-host/a/getmeta?id=10 via commons-http, i dont' understand why it would produce a popup to the client.  YOU are the client.  If you're just pointing at this URL via an image or an iframe (other other means via the browser) then you're SOL. you'll need to change that to hit a proxy servlet on your side and you'll need to sit as a layer between the client and the site minder protected resource. how you gather their username/password is up to you in your application, but you'll have to pass it along when talking to the SM protected resource